# VB.NET regular expression replace string

Tags: regex, vb.net, replace

I have got a string that I need to replace by using wildcards in a VB.Net code.
I found out that I may need to use the Regular expressions but I am new to it.

I would like to change the following strings:

- `John;-4;5`
- `John;20;15`
- `John;-255;2`

where the `-4;5` etc are the changing parts of the string into `newValue`

I used a standard string replace but that does not seem to work:

```
newString = oldString.Replace(oldString & ";" & "*" & ";" & "*", "newValue")
```

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Regular expressions are **not** wildcards. They are a very different beast.

Comment: `John;-?\d+;-?\d+` :p

Comment: What does newString look like for each of the samples given a specific newValue?

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
ResultString = Regex.Replace(SubjectString, "(-*\d+;*)+", "newValue")
```

This will replace any occurrence of numbers (with or without -ve sign) followed by ; or not. Therefore your sample data of

```
John;-4;5
John;20;15
John;-255;2
John;123;234;5;32;45;543
```

will become

```
John;newValue
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a multiline regex with the following expression

;(.*)[-+]?\b[0-9]*.?[0-9]+\b

so maybe something like this to replace all instances with a blank string, I havent tested this because i cant at the moment but if this fails then replace the multiline with singleline

```
Dim SourceString as string = "John;-4;5" & vbcrlf & "John;20;15"
Dim ReplaceString as string = ""
Dim result As String =   Regex.Replace(SourceString,";(.*)[-+]?\b[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+\b",ReplaceString,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase or RegexOptions.Multiline)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always try this

```
newString = 
oldString.Replace(oldString,"newValue").replace(";","NewVal").replace("*","Newval)
```

this will althrough only replace chars in oldstring

I would try this :

```
dim val as string = "John;-4;5" ' Or any other string like this

Dim arr() As String = val.Split(";")

'manipulate string from here 

'arr(0) is John
'arr(1) is -4
'arr(2) is -5
```

then build your new value string

```
val = arr(0) & ";" & "newval" & ";" & "newVal"
```